TypeScript ESLint: Rule to sort interface props alphabetically, with functions going last?
I'm looking for an ESLint rule with similar capabilities to react/jsx-sort-props but for interfaces and types, where I can require to sort interface members alphabetically, with members of type function going last.
Wrong example:
interface I {
    b: string;
    ab: () => void;
    a: string;
}

Correct example:
interface I {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    ab: () => void;
}

Does a rule for this exist? So far, I've only found rules that sort members alphabetically, but they don't have a setting to require functions to go last.
